# Docker with .NET 5.0 and React.js errors on run

Tags: docker

[I followed this Microsoft article about creating a React.js client with .NET 5.0 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022)

I am attempting to create the Dockerfile and am able to successfully run the docker container for the .NET side (autogenerated) with no problem. I am able to "docker build" the react app with no problem but I get an error when I run it.

```
reactfrontend@0.1.0 prestart /app
node aspnetcore-https && node aspnetcore-react
events.js:292
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn dotnet ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn dotnet',
  path: 'dotnet',
  spawnargs: [
    'dev-certs',
    'https',
    '--export-path',
    '/root/.aspnet/https/reactfrontend.pem',
    '--format',
    'Pem',
    '--no-password'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactfrontend@0.1.0 prestart: `node aspnetcore-https && node aspnetcore-react`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactfrontend@0.1.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-27T12_34_43_487Z-debug.log
```

I was unable to find the script in the file structure to debug. Let me know if this is missing info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get a workaround by using an nginx image to assist, not sure why this allowed it to work as opposed to a standard React Dockerfile.

```
# Step 1
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

There's probably a more correct answer to this but for a band-aid fix, this worked for me.